# What is the average magnitude of a random element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Sorry if this isn't a very well-defined question, I am new to probability and I am just curious whether this question is meaningful, and if so, can be answered.

Suppose that as an experiment, we select a random element of $\mathbb{N}$. We keep repeating this proccess. What is the average size of our results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define what kind of 'randomness' we are dealing with here. I assume you've already heard of probability distributions, like uniform, Binomial or Gaussian distributions. There can be no meaningful answer before one defines how 'random' this process of choice is.

That said, most situations in which people say 'random' with no additional context, they mean 'uniformly random'. However, the natural numbers (and more generally any countable space) do not admit a uniform probability measure.

That's because if every number had the same probability of being chosen, say $\epsilon\geq0$, then the sum of their probabilities would be either $0$ if $\epsilon=0$ or unbounded if $\epsilon>0$. For it to be a probability measure, this result should be equal to $1$.

Comment: That makes sense thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: @Fimp couldn't you define picking an element of $\mathbb{N}$ " at random as a picking a number from a "reciprocal" continuous distribution in the real interval $(0,1]$, then taking the floor of the reciprocal. By "reciprocal" distribution I mean one where the probability is inversely proportional to the value of the RV.

Comment: @Χpẘ I don't know if perhaps you misunderstood my answer, but I did not mean to say that there is no way to choose an element of $\mathbb{N}$. The problem in fact is that there are many such ways, but no 'canonical' way; your suggestion is one possibility. Any sequence $(a_n)$ of nonnegative reals with finite sum $S=\sum a_n>0$ defines a probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ via $\mathbb{P}(n)=\frac{a_n}{S}$. The thing is, we need to specify beforehand which probability distribution we're talking about.

Comment: The OP said "randomly" pick an element, so 1) I was assuming a uniform distribution. But then the problem seemed to be, "2) how to define a uniform distribution over an infinitely long interval?" So my comment above was after taking those two leaps (which I neglected to state).

Comment: There is no uniform distribution over the natural numbers; this is shown in the answer. Your suggestion is not uniform.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the problem isn't with uniformity, but that the area under the PDF curve is infinite, so can't be normalized to 1. The area under the curve is equal to limit of $ln(x) + 1$ as $x \Rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a probability distribution.

I'll assume by $\mathbb{N}$, you mean the set of positive integers.

Thus, to select a "random" element of $\mathbb{N}$, you need a sequence of nonnegative real numbers

$$p_1,p_2,p_3,...$$

such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n =  p_1 + p_2 + p_3 +\,\cdots = 1$$

where $p_n$ is the probability of selecting the value $n$.

The distribution can't be uniform, since that would mean
$$p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = \cdots = p,\,\text{say}$$
but there's no real number $p$ such that

$$p + p + p +\,\cdots = 1$$

Thus, there's no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{N}$.

There are lots of possible non-uniform distributions, but no standard, default distribution. In any given context, the distribution would have to be specified in advance.

Once a valid distribution is specified, the concept of "average magnitude" can be interpreted as the expected value of a single choice. Mathematically, the expected value is just the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty np_n = p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 +\,\cdots$$

however this sum might diverge (to $\infty$), in which case, one could say informally that the expected value is infinite, or more precisely, that the expected value doesn't exist as a real number.

Two examples . . .

$(1)\;\,$If we let 
$$p_n = \frac{1}{2^n},\;\text{for all}\;n \in \mathbb{N}$$

we have a valid distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$$

and the expected value is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty np_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n} = 2$$

$(2)\;\,$If instead we let 
$$p_n = \frac{6}{\pi^2n^2},\;\text{for all}\;n \in \mathbb{N}$$
we have a valid distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ since

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6}{\pi^2n^2}\\[4pt] 
&= \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\\[4pt] 
&= \left(\frac{6}{\pi^2}\right)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\\[4pt] 
&=1\\[4pt] 
\end{align*}

but the expected value is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty np_n = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$